# How to use Python keyword via kwargs in python

Tags: python, pandas, keyword

i have to read csv file by using given parametes by user like "sep","encoding",etc`.. my code is below, file1.py is used to read the csv file with parameters given by the user. Here, in my code, i'm not facing any issue, but dataframe is not correctly delimited due to the arguments is coming as string datatype.

can anyone help me to convert string to pandas dataframe argument in below case ?

Thanks in advance

file1.py

```
import pandas as pd
def csvTodataframe(inputcsv,**kwargs):
    if(kwargs):
        param_list = ""
        count =0
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            if(count == 0):
                param_list = key+"="+"'"+value+"'"
            else:
                param_list = param_list+","+key+"="+"'"+value+"'"
            #### param list will be sep='"|"',encoding='utf-16'
            count +=1
        df = pd.read_csv(inputcsv,param_list)
```

file2.py

```
    import file1
    df = file1.csvTodataframe('test.csv',sep='"|"',encoding='utf-16')
```

Comment: how about just `df.read_csv(input_csv, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the quick response. i tried that ,its throwing error that, "Typeerror: unhashable dict"

Comment: make sure you don't forget the `**` before `kwargs` inside `read_csv`

Comment: omg. its working as expected now :) Many thanks for the help @QuangHoang